Comparing between Kantorovich and Gilmore-Gomory formulations to solve Cutting stock problem by column generation
The well-known approach to solving the cutting stock problem is the Gilmore-Gomory (GG) formulation in a column generation procedure. The master and subproblems of GG formulation are: (for simplicity I dropped the indices and parameters definition)
\begin{align*}
\text{Min}_{(MP)} \quad & \sum_{p \in P} x_p \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \sum_{p \in P} a_{i,p} x_p \geq r_i \ , \forall i \in I\\
                        & x_p \geq 0.
\end{align*}
$$-----------------$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Min}_{(SP)} \quad & 1- \sum_{i \in I} \pi_i y_i \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \sum_{i \in I} w_i y_i \leq W\\
                        & y_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+.
\end{align*}
Indeed, Kantorovich also proposed a MIP formulation to solve the CSP.
\begin{align*}
\text{Min} \quad & \sum_k y_k \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \sum_k x_{i,k} \geq r_i \ , \forall i \\
\quad & \sum_i w_i x_{i,k} \leq W y_k \ , \forall k \\
                        & y_k \in \{0,1\}, x_{i,k} \in \mathbb{Z}^+.
\end{align*}
As far as I know, the GG formulation came from the Kantorovich formulation in the Dantzig-Wolfe reformulation context. The DW reformulation of the Kantorovich model is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\text{Min}_{(MP)} \quad & \sum_k \sum_p \lambda_{k}^p \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \sum_k \sum_p a_{i,k}^p \lambda_{k}^p \geq r_i \ , \forall i \\
\quad & \sum_p \lambda_{k}^p \leq 1 \ , \forall k \\
                        & \lambda_{k}^p \geq 0.
\end{align*}
Now, my questions are:

How can the GG model be derived from the Kantorovich model?
How the variables $y_k$ can be interpreted as $\lambda_{k}^p$?
Based on the Kantorovich model, what would the subproblem objective function be?


It might not answer all your questions directly, but I recommend Lübbecke's excellent video tutorial on Branch-and-Price. He goes over the two formulations and explains quite clearly what's going on. Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vx2LNKx48vY

@J.Dionisio, thank you so much for your comment. I will see that ASAP.

The trick is that since the big rolls are identical, you can aggregate the $\lambda$ variables:
$$
\sum_k \lambda_k^p = \lambda^p = x_p 
$$
Also, since you are minimizing the number of big rolls, you can ommit the convexity constraints, which yields the CG model.
The interpretation of the $y_k$ variables is: $y_k$ takes value $1$ if and only if roll $k$ is selected. The difference with $\lambda_p$ is that although $p$ also represents a roll, its structure is already entirely defined (via $a_i^p$). On the contrary, roll $k$ is not defined; it is defined via constraints $\sum_i w_i x_{i,k} \le W y_k$.

Thank you so much for your informative answer. Would you please, is it normal to ommit the convexity constraint when we talk about the identical things? E.g machines, rolls, stations, ...?

Also, suppose in a feasible solution there would be the variable $y_k$ that takes zero value. By ommiting the convexity constraint how we can ensure it does not cause a numerical issue?

I am not sure to understand what you mean by your last paragraph. Would you elaborate more about that, please?

I had $y_k$ confused with $y_i$. Fixed.

The fact the rolls are identical is the reason why you can aggregate the variables, not why you can ommit the convexity constraint. The convexity constraint can be ignored, because of the objective function (minimize the number of rolls).

thank you so much for your edited answer as well as your last comment. I think I need to check something and I get back to you if I have any further questions.
